# removed an elastic IP from a single instance elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried creating a new elastic IP and attaching directly to the EC2 instance, but that did not work.

Is it possible to manually attach an Elastic IP to a single intance Elastic Beanstalk configuration?

Comment: What didn't work exactly?

Comment: I am still not able to access my instance via the domain name assigned by Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: "via the domain name assigned by Elastic Beanstalk" its not posible due to it's the DNS of your Elastic Load Balancer. You must to use your EC2 DNS or public IP.